# How to run proguard in my spring mvc application, no jar but for classes?

Tags: java, spring, maven, proguard

Spring mvc applications don't have jars, they have wars (.war or exploded).

My maven build creates an exploded war in:

```
/myapp/target/myapp-1.0/
```

and my classes are in:

```
/myapp/target/myapp-1.0/web-inf/classes
```

I want to obfuscate everything in the namespace com.maypp.*

How can I do this?

So far I have this:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>?????</injar>
                <inFilter>com.myapp.*</inFilter>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

P.S I see these options in tutorials, what are they doing?

```
<options>
16.
<option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
17.
<option>-keep public class
18.
${project.build.mainClass} { *; }</option>
19.
</options>
```

Comment: no my packaging is an exploded war

Comment: so what you want to obfuscate?

Comment: I want obfuscate my /target/myapp-1.0/web-inf/classes  (the .class files, this is a web application so I my maven build produces an exploded war).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [ant task docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/ant.html), the `injar` tag:

> Specifies the program jars (or wars, ears, zips, or directories).

Additionally:

> The jar tags are path tags, so they can have any of the path attributes (or nested elements). The most common attributes are [bunch of attributes like `"path"`].

Comment: I have this now, but it still can't find the classes, error during mvn clean install: `Error: The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you specify the proper '-injars' options?`  my pom.xml has `<injar>${project.build.finalName}.war</injar>`

Comment: is should be my .war file name, myapp.war (that is what I am assuming it is)  while running mvn clean install, it shows `proguard -injars /path/to/myapp/target/myapp.war (!META-INF/maven/**,com.myapp.*)`